# Como usar Media Queries para sites responsivos baseados nas dimensões dos devices?

Tags: css, media-queries

Confesso que webdesign não é meu forte, por preciso tirar algumas dúvidas cruciais em relação a sites responsivos. Entendo que para definir formatações para diversos dispositivos usa-se o Media Queries. Por ex.:

Criei essa media para testes:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body tr td{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

No Motorola G4 Plus (aquele com ghost touch), aparece perfeito. Ele tem 5.5'' polegadas, porém em um outro smartphone com a tela 4.5'' a fonte sobrepôs a coluna.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- Como faço para que o site seja visível de forma satisfatória em todos os devices baseados em suas dimensões, ou seja, qual Media Query uso para cada dimensão dos devices. Ex.: 4.5'' (@media...), 5.5'' (@media...), etc?
- Existe um padrão de media-queries baseados nas dimensões das telas dos devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quiser servir TODOS os devices seu código vai virar uma loucura e vai ser de impossível manutenção, já que a todo momento pipoca um device novo e que pode ter dimensões novas.

Recomendo que você trabalhe com o combo media queries + responsive. Assim você consegue pegar os devices mais usados do mercado e ainda ser bem visualizado em muitos outros.

Uma boa técnica pra isso é o mobile first: você pensa no seu site primeiro em celular e depois vai readequando os elementos para tamanhos de tela maiores. Assim, você evita ter elementos que se sobreponham. Se encaixou no menor, vai ser mais fácil encaixar no maior.

Não adianta passar uma lista com os tamanhos mais usados porque isso vai variar com o tempo. Isso faria qualquer resposta passar a receber downvote com o tempo, já que ficaria obsoleta.

Comment: Olá Bruno. Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas o que seria combo media queries + responsive?

Comment: Responsividade é a técnica de construir um site fluído, com elementos que se adaptam de acordo com o tamanho (geralmente com elementos dimensionados usando %).

Comment: Certo. Só para entender melhor sobre como definir o media queries baseado nas telas dos devices. Usando como exemplo o Motorola G4  Plus, nas especificações diz que a tela é de 1080 x 1920 pixel, então se eu quisesse usá-lo como modelo, eu teria que fazer dessa forma  **@media (max-width: 1080px)** ?

Comment: Tem um artigo bem interessante sobre como usar os media queries aqui: https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/

Comment: Veja o problema: sua resposta está correta APENAS se o celular estiver na vertical. Se o usuário gira-lo 90º, a lógica passa a ser outra. Entende?

Comment: @Fox.11 Se minha resposta ajudou você, favor aceitar como correta. =)

Comment: Perfeito Bruno. Obrigado.